# contract state variable does not change after call the function

Tags: contract-development

I have deployed the contract, the code is [here](https://gist.github.com/minishine/da46867d9de43a6af6cdc4eb5caf9412), very easy. Then get the instance

`ballot1 = eth.contract(abi).at(addr)`

call the function 

`ballot1.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[1], 'xiaoB', {from:eth.accounts[0]})`

continue minned after confirmed

> ballot1.voters()
>   ["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", false, 0, 0, 0]

the state variable was still empty

Comment: Try `ballot1.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[1], 'xiaoB', {from:eth.accounts[0], gas:200000})`

Comment: @BokkyPooBah I have tried, the transaction has been minned, but the state variable didn't change

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `ballot1.voters(eth.accounts[1])` instead of just `ballot1.voters()`. Explanation follows.

When you mark a variable `public`, solidity creates getter functions, so for example if you make a variable called `address public my_address`, it will make the equivalent to:

```
function my_address() constant returns (address) {
   return my_address;
}
```

You're trying to use such a getter function for `voters`. However, `voters` is a mapping, which is a list of keys (in this case of type `address`) to values (of type `Voter`). You might expect that it would have a auto-generated a function so that called without parameters, it would return all the keys to the mapping, or maybe the keys and their values. However, you can't iterate a mapping; There is no way to get the keys in solidity unless you already know them, so the Solidity compiler can't do anything sensible with just a call to a public mapping with no arguments. What it's done instead is to auto-generate a function with an argument for the key. When you're calling it without a parameter, it's imagining you called it with the parameter `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, which returns an empty mapping since you haven't set any values for a voter with the address `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.

If you do need to iterate through the keys of `voters`, what you can do is create a parallel data structure in the form of an array called `voter_addresses[]`, make that public, and set it at the same time as you set a value in the `voters` mapping. If you mark *that* public, you should (IIRC) be able to get the resulting array by calling `voter_addresses()`.

Comment: I have modified the code,  added a state var `votersNum`, code [like this](https://gist.github.com/minishine/da46867d9de43a6af6cdc4eb5caf9412)
then executed 
`ballot1 = eth.contract(abi).at(addr);
ballot1.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[1], 'xiaoB', {from:eth.accounts[0]});
`
then minned, get the votersNum
`ballot1.votersNum()`
it was still `0`, didn't increase

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code just to change the Solidity version to match my environment:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Ballot {
    // 投票人结构体
    struct Voter {
        bytes32 name;
        bool voted;  // 是否已经投过票
        uint vote;   // 投给谁了
        uint givenRightTime; // 被授权时间
        uint votetime; // 投票时间
    }

    // 候选项结构体
    struct Proposal {
        bytes32 name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    address public chairperson;  // 投票发起人

    mapping(address => Voter) public voters; // 投票群众

    Proposal[] public proposals;  // 候选选项

    event voteCast(address from, bytes32 proposal, uint voteTime);

    // 构造方法
    function Ballot(bytes32[] proposalNames) {
        chairperson = msg.sender;

        // 初始化候选项
        for(uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
            proposals.push(Proposal({
                name: proposalNames[i],
                voteCount: 0
            }));

        }
    }

    function giveRightToVote(address voter, bytes32 voterName) {
        // 如果不是投票发起人分配，或者分配的地址已经投过，抛异常
        if(msg.sender != chairperson || voters[voter].voted) {
            //throw;
        }
        voters[voter].name = voterName;
        voters[voter].voted = false;
        voters[voter].votetime = 0;
        voters[voter].givenRightTime = now;
    }

    // 投票
    function vote(uint proposalIndex) {
        Voter sender = voters[msg.sender];
        // 检查是否已经投过
        if(sender.voted) {
            throw;
        }

        proposals[proposalIndex].voteCount += 1;

        // 修改状态
        sender.voted = true;
        sender.votetime = now;
        sender.vote = proposalIndex;

        voteCast(msg.sender, proposals[proposalIndex].name, now);
    }

    // 获取获胜者编号
    function winningProposalIndex() constant
            returns (uint winningProposalIndex)
    {
        uint winningVoteCount = 0;
        for (uint p = 0; p < proposals.length; p++) {
            if (proposals[p].voteCount > winningVoteCount) {
                winningVoteCount = proposals[p].voteCount;
                winningProposalIndex = p;
            }
        }
    }

    // 获取获胜者姓名
    function winnerName() constant
            returns (bytes32 winnerName)
    {
        winnerName = proposals[winningProposalIndex()].name;
    }
}
```

And loaded your code into Browser Solidity, connected to my `--dev` `geth` instance with `eth.accounts[0]` unlocked.

[image]

I executed the transaction `giveRightToVote(...)` with the parameters `"0x0014060ff383c9b21c6840a3b14aab06741e5c49","xiaoB"` where the address is my `eth.accounts[1]`.

The then called the autogenerated function `voters(...)` with the parameter `"0x0014060ff383c9b21c6840a3b14aab06741e5c49"` and it returned the expected results:

[image]

In `geth`, I confirmed the returned value from `voters(...)` using the command:

```
> web3.toUtf8("0x7869616f42000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
"xiaoB"
```

I then ran the following in `geth`:

```
> var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"proposalIndex","type":"uint256"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposals","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"voteCount","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"chairperson","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"winningProposalIndex","outputs":[{"name":"winningProposalIndex","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"voters","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"voted","type":"bool"},{"name":"vote","type":"uint256"},{"name":"givenRightTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"votetime","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"winnerName","outputs":[{"name":"winnerName","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"voter","type":"address"},{"name":"voterName","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"giveRightToVote","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"proposalNames","type":"bytes32[]"}],"type":"constructor","payable":true},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"proposal","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"voteTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"voteCast","type":"event"}];
undefined
> var addr = "0x0d41ff746994e76fd0ad575ca852e447559e8089";
undefined
> var ballot1 = eth.contract(abi).at(addr);
undefined
> ballot1.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[2], 'account2user', {from:eth.accounts[0]});
"0x07c24de5b92499f05570a2c648bc8f30ae7a23676bddf29ad00aea4a8b21da58"
// Wait for the transaction to be mined, then check it worked correctly
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x07c24de5b92499f05570a2c648bc8f30ae7a23676bddf29ad00aea4a8b21da58")
{
  blockHash: "0xf11c183e434266199912cfbb97984c7a527f0c0858dd238dd5bca290cf8c4190",
  blockNumber: 30084,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 74723,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 74723,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0x6095d7e4c505418b78d12034270b4d88c27d4921c71cbd1767d525cb3c8c5319",
  to: "0x0d41ff746994e76fd0ad575ca852e447559e8089",
  transactionHash: "0x07c24de5b92499f05570a2c648bc8f30ae7a23676bddf29ad00aea4a8b21da58",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
> ballot1.voters(eth.accounts[2]);
["0x6163636f756e7432757365720000000000000000000000000000000000000000", false, 0, 1482575492, 0]
> web3.toUtf8("0x6163636f756e7432757365720000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
"account2user"
```

Your code is working as expected. Just follow the steps above. As `@Edmund Edgar` has stated, you will need to pass the account parameter to `ballot1.voters(...)`.

---

### Update Responding To Comment Below

1. As you are sending your transaction from from `eth.accounts[0]`, you only have to unlock `eth.accounts[0]`.
2. You may want to try Browser Solidity - it's a bit easier to interactively work out what is going on. To do this:

   - Point your browser to https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity.
   - Change **Branch** on the top left from **master** to **gh-pages**.
   - Download the .zip file onto your computer. The current .zip file has the name `browser-solidity-6698a74.zip`.
   - Unzip the .zip file into a subdirectory on your computer.
   - Navigate to the new subdirectory.
   - Load `index.html` in this subdirectory in your web browser.
   - In Browser Solidity, select the **cube** icon on the top right.
   - Click on **Web3 Provider** and confirm that you want to connect to your local Ethereum node.
   - Load your Solidity code in the left pane.
   - Click on the **Create** button after specifying your contract's constructor parameters on the input box to the right of the Create button.
   - Click on the **giveRightToVote** button after specifying the parameters - see the screenprint I've attached.
   - Click on the **voters** button after specifying the parameters - see the screenprint I've attached.

Comment: I have run the steps as you in `geth` (replace the addr `truffle migrate` returned), but still not work. `ballot1.voters(eth.accounts[2]);` returns  `["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", false, 0, 0, 0]`

I deployed the contract via truffle, executed `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate`, and it returns the address. Except this, all other steps in geth console are exactly the same.

Comment: Could help me with the question above

Comment: I was testing with `eth.accounts[2]` for a unique address to test with. Presumably you have tested with your appropriate account, `eth.accounts[1]`?

Comment: I have 5 accounts,`eth.accounts[2]`  has the value `0x8a0fbdf7aa1d7e8e6aabc51719912f8f6de00330` , I started the geth by this command `./geth --dev --identity "newEth-dev" --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "./cdata-dev" --port 30305 --rpcapi "personal,db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 999   console`

Comment: Do you unlock your accounts before sending the transactions?

Comment: yes, before I executed `truffle migrate`, I have unlocked the accounts[0] `personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], '123456', 100000)`, do you mean  that I should unlock acounts[2] ?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the question by adding the parameter `gas`

`ballot1.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[2], 'account2user', {from:eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000});`

but while I called the function at the second time as above

`ballot1.giveRightToVote.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[3], 'account3user', {from:eth.accounts[0]});`

without `gas`, it successed too. Really unimaginable